# ifstream pipe and multiple (sequential) writers

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I'm reading from a named pipe on Linux using `std::ifstream`. If the writing end of the file is closed, I can not continue reading from the pipe through the stream. For some reason I have to `clear()`, `close()` and `open()` the stream again to continue reading. Is this expected? How can I avoid the `close() open()` on a pipe when writers `close()` and `open()` the pipe at will?

Background: I believe the `close() open()` I have to do is causing the writer to sometimes receive `SIGPIPE` which I would like to avoid.

More details - I am using this code to read a stream

```
// read single line
stream_("/tmp/delme", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
std::getline(stream_, output_filename_);
std::cout << "got filename: " << output_filename_ << std::endl;
#if 0
// this fixes the problem
stream_.clear();
stream_.close();
stream_.open("/tmp/delme", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
// now the read blocks until data is available
#endif

// read more binary data
const int hsize = 4096+4;
std::array<char, hsize> b;
stream_.read(&b[0], hsize);
std::string tmp(std::begin(b), std::begin(b)+hsize);
std::cout << "got header: " << tmp << std::endl;
```

`/tmp/delme` is my pipe. I do `echo "foo" > /tmp/delme` and I get the `foo` in `output_filename_` but the stream does not block there, (it should, there is no more data), it proceeds to read garbage. If I enable the code within the `ifdef` it works. Why?

Thanks, 
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Since you use std::getLine(), maybe you need to use an extra "\n" to signal the end of a line:

```
echo -e "foo\n" > /tmp/delme
```

instead of just

```
echo "foo" > /tmp/delme
```

This should at least get rid of the garbage reading.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but no, that is not the case. echo automatically outputs \n on my plattform. It can be prevented by passing the -n argument but that is not what I am doing.